# How do insert a record into a from a string using split function in MVC4?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all i have a string like this which i am passing an ajax function to my controller action method

```
       Brand1~1001=>undefined_undefined|
           Category1~2001=>1001_Brand1|
           Category2~2002=>1001_Brand1|
                  Product3~3003=>2002_Category2|
                      Product4~3004=>Product3~3003|
                 Product5~3005=>2002_Category2|
                 Product6~3006=>2002_Category2|
```

and i have an Menus table in db i had added that as an entity model to my project

```
       Menus

          [MenuID],[MenuName],[ParentID]
```

and i have model like this

```
           public class MenuItems
            {
              public List<MenuItems> GetALL { get; set; }
              public int MenuId { get; set; }
              public string MenuName { get; set; }
              public int parentId { get; set; }
            }
```

now i want to split the string i have and insert into the above table like this

```
           [MenuID],[MenuName],[ParentID]
            1001   ,Brand1    ,null
            2001   ,category1 ,1001
            2002   ,category2 ,1001
            3003   ,product3  ,2002
            3004   ,product4  ,3003
            3005   ,product5  ,2002
            3006   ,product6  ,2002
```

in the above string Brand1~1001=>undefined_undefined| here Brand1~1001 is the parentmenu and 1001 is the id of the menu
Category1~2001=>1001_Brand1| and here Category1~2001 is the sub menu of the 1001_Brand1 i think you all got waht i amtrying to do can any one help me here please

what i amtrying

```
    public ActionResult MenuDrag()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult MenuDrag(string menustring)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(menustring))
        {
            string[] menus = menustring.Split('|');
            foreach (var m in menus)
            {
                string[] list = m.Split('>'); 
                //stuck from here confused what to do next and how do i insert the data in my accordingly
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there just replace your post method with this

```
      [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult MenuDrag(string menustring)
    {            
        MenuItems items = new MenuItems();
      //check the string for empty
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(menustring))
        {
            string[] menus = menustring.Split('|');
            foreach (var m in menus)
            {
                if (m != "")
                {
                    string[] list = m.Split('>');


                    string[] menu = list[0].Split('~');
                    string[] parents = list[1].Split('~');
                    items.MenuItemID = Convert.ToInt16(menu[1]);
                    items.MenuName = menu[0].ToString();
                    if (parents[0] == "undefined")
                    {
                        items.ParentID = 0;
                        db.MenuItems.Add(items);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int parentid=Convert.ToInt16(parents[0]);
                        var menuid = from me in db.MenusMains where me.MenuItemID == parentid select new { MenuID = me.MenuID };
                        foreach (var id in menuid)
                        {
                            items.ParentID = Convert.ToInt16(id.MenuID);                               
                        }
                        db.MenuItems.Add(items);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }                      
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }

}
```

i had used

```
          if (m != "")
            {
            }
```

since u may get an index out of bound exception there since when in your string at this

```
  string[] menus = menustring.Split('|');
```

u will get an empty ('|') you have to handle this

hope this works